# How do I extract specific rows from a PDL matrix?

Tags: perl, pdl

Suppose I have:

```
$a = [
      [1, 0, 1]
      [0, 1, 0]
      [0, 1, 1]
     ]
```

and I want to extract all rows where `$row[2] == 1`. My resulting piddle would look like:

```
$b = [
      [1, 0, 1]
      [0, 1, 1]
     ]
```

Is this possible with PDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `which` to generate a list of indexes of your matrix which have a value of 1 in the third column

```perl
which($aa->index(2) == 1)
```

and pass this to `dice_axis`, which will select the rows with the given indexes. Axis 0 is the columns and axis 1 is the rows, so the code looks like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use PDL;

my $aa = pdl <<__END_PDL__;
[
  [1, 0, 1]
  [0, 1, 0]
  [0, 1, 1]
]
__END_PDL__

my $result = $aa->dice_axis(1, which($aa->index(2) == 1));

print $result;
```

#### output

```
[
 [1 0 1]
 [0 1 1]
]
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I can use multiple conditions with something like `$aa->dice_axis(1, which($aa->index(0) == 1 & $aa->index(2) == 1))`. Is that correct?

Comment: @marcantonio: Pretty much yes. But `&` in Perl is a bitwise mask operator; you need `&&` or `and`, which are identical but with different precedences.

Comment: I came across this: http://pdl.perl.org/?docs=FAQ&title=PDL::FAQ%20-%20Frequently%20Asked%20Questions#Q:-6.11-Logical-operators-and-piddles---and-dont-work which is why I used `&` rather than `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to `PDL`, but it seems like you can use `which` result as a mask.

You need to `transpose` original variable first, then `transpose` it back after using `slice`.

```
pdl> $a = pdl [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]

pdl> p which($a(2) == 1)
[0 2]

pdl> p $a->transpose    

[
 [1 0 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [1 0 1]
]

pdl> p $a->transpose->slice(which($a(2) == 1))->transpose

[
 [1 0 1]
 [0 1 1]
]
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in a Perl program without the addition of `use PDL::NiceSlice`. This module allows more concise `slice`/`dice` expressions, but it uses source filtering, which is generally a Bad Thing.